# Python Schedule Tasks for Processing by One Worker (if possible without Serialization)

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, fastapi, worker

I have a main process that needs to run some calculations regularly (every second). These calculations heavily depend on the system state (very complex). I also provide an (async, FastAPI to be specific) API to interact with the system state (e.g. modify config etc.), as the system state is very complex and should not be changed during a calculation, I cannot put it in some kind of shared object (e.g. Pyro or SharedMemory).

Therefore, I need to have the API schedule function calls and wait for an answer. The main process must regularly check for function calls, execute them, and somehow write the results back for the waiting API call.

To me, this seems to be not that unpopular of a problem, but so far I have not found a good solution. For more context, this is how I solved it previously (I used websockets instead of a (REST) API):

I had a process to read incoming messages, then serialize the arguments and function specification and write it to a queue (redis db). The main process then fetched the tasks from the queue, deserialized, executed them and wrote the serialized results directly back to the websocket, where the clients where listening for their answer. As you probably know by now, this involes a lot of serialization and is not very clean (at least imho).

I have put a lot of effort into finding the correct solution, but so far nothing has really been what I have been looking for.